# Using the selected tab in a TabControl to clear a variable - WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, tabcontrol

I have a window which contains a a TabControl with 2 TabItems inside it. Inside the second tab, there is a TextBox with a binding to a string property inside my view model. I want to be able to clear this property (or the TextBox since it is bound it will will by association, clear the property) whenever the user clicks on a different tab (and also if the user closes the window). I'm hoping I can achieve this with only the XAML since I am trying to follow the MVVM pattern (so no code behind and my view model shouldn't know of the TabControl or TextBox that is in my view).

I have tried a few different things and can't quite get it working and while I'm getting better at WPF, I'm still fairly new to it. Inside my tabs I also have ListViews and ComboBoxes, which from my understanding will bubble the SelectionChanged event (same as when the tab selection is changed) so I should probably stay away from that. Any help would be appreciated.

Here was one of my attempts (snippet showing the gist):

```
<TabControl>
<TabItem>
    ...Stuff in first tab goes here
</TabItem>

<TabItem Header="Rules">
    <TabItem.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{IsSelected}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="UserBox" Property="Text" Value="" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TabItem.Style>


    <GroupBox>
        <UniformGrid>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource rulesViewModel}, Path=RulesList}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Rules"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>

            <DockPanel>
                <TextBox Name="UserBox" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource rulesViewModel}, Path=User}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </UniformGrid>
    </GroupBox>
</TabItem>
```

I'm pretty sure the line that reads **Binding="{IsSelected}"** is wrong. But I'm not sure how to target the correct property. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to use the interactivity library to catch the `SelectionChanged` property and change the property. It would look something like this:

```
<TabControl>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding Path=Path.To.ViewModel}" PropertyName="MyProperty" Value="" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TabControl>
```

You can also choose to change the value of the TextBox - in which case you'd need to modify the `ChangePropertyAction` object to look like this:

```
<ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="UserBox" PropertyName="Text" Value="" />
```

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but it doesn't seem to be working. I've tried different events and none seem to be responding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the SelectedIndex = -1 of the tab whose content you want to clear on other tabs click.

SelectedIndex = -1 is of the default tab so basically we are making this tab as the default one. Now the condition becomes that

if SelectedIndex ! = -1, text should be cleared
or at application shutdown, text should be cleared

I've provided you with the logic, code can now be written :)